# NoReverseMatch when using @permalink and get_absolute_url()

Tags: python, django

I know this seems to be a common problem with many solutions, but even after trying every solution I have come across, I still have this issue.

Models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True,
                        help_text='Unique value for product page URL, created form name.')
description = models.TextField()
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
meta_keywords = models.CharField("Meta Keywords",max_length=255, 
                                 help_text='Comma-delimited set of SEO keywords for meta tag')
meta_description = models.CharField("Meta Description", max_length=255,
                                    help_text='Content for description meta tag')
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'categories'
    ordering = ['name']
    verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

@models.permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    #return ('catalog.views.show_category',(),{'category_slug' : str(self.slug)})
    return ('catalog_category', (), { 'category_slug' : str(self.slug) })
```

Views:

```
def index(request, template_name="catalog/index.html"):
    page_title = 'Anime and Manga'
    return render_to_response(template_name, locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def show_category(request, category_slug, template_name="catalog/category.html"):
    c = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
    products = c.product_set.all()
    page_title = c.name
    meta_keywords = c.meta_keywords
    meta_description = c.meta_description
    return render_to_response(template_name, locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Urls:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('catalog.views', 
                   (r'^$', 'index', { 'template_name':'catalog/index.html' },  'catalog_home'),
                   (r'^category/(?P<category_slug>[-\W]+)/$', 'show_category', 
                    {'template_name':'catalog/category.html'}, 'catalog_category'),
```

When I go into the shell and try:

> reverse ('catalog_home')

...it returns:

> '/'

...which is correct. However, when I try:

> reverse ('catalog_category', kwargs={'category_slug':'action'}

...it returns:

> NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'catalog_category' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'category_slug': 'action'}' not found.

Despite the code sample I have entered here, the indentation in my real code is correct, so the permalink is under the Category Class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have used `\W` in your regex, which means "any character **except** alphanumeric". I expect you meant `\w`.

Comment: YES THANK YOU!! All of my torment because of a big W!